# shell_exec problems in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I have some PHP code that I need to start a ruby script in the background on the server. But the script doesn't want to work. All the script does for now is get input and echo it back.

I invoke it like so:

```
shell_exec("./fifo_test.r < input.fifo > buffer &");
```

This causes the PHP to hang indefinitely. But it works fine when I run it directly.

```
root@ip-xxxxx:/var/www/test# su www-data
$ sh -c ./fifo_test.r < input.fifo > buffer &
$ echo test > input.fifo
$ cat buffer
Got: test
```

Here is the process info:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxx:~$ ps -ef | grep fifo
www-data  1076     1  0 00:39 ?        00:00:00 sh -c ./fifo_test.r < input.fifo > buffer &
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

EDIT: I can unfreeze the PHP by manually adding to input.fifo. Then it works fine afterward. But it waits for that first input forever when PHP starts it. I am not sure how to avoid this!

Comment: shell_exec and similar functions like exec, passthru, etc. are considered dangerous and should be disabled in your php configuration.

Comment: Why would I disable something that I am trying to use explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

**If the PHP script is generating the input**, use [popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). That way, you can avoid using a named pipe.

**If the input is coming from some other source**, it is best not to have your PHP script (or the Ruby script it executes) read directly from a FIFO. I know this from trying to write a Web interface for displaying captured network packets in real-time years ago and encountering a similar problem.

I would instead write a simple server program that accepts Unix socket connections. This server can accept the input either from a FIFO or another socket connection and then send it to all running instances of the PHP or Ruby script. You can write such a server in the CLI version of PHP using [only](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) [core](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php) [features](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php), although [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/) (for JavaScript), [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) (for Python), and [EventMachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/) (for Ruby) are designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the `nohup` command in your shell call. This should cause the program to return immediately so PHP isn't waiting. The code in your case would look like so:

```
shell_exec("nohup ./fifo_test.r < input.fifo > buffer &");
```

Hope that helps!